# How to reference $workflow:xx via a variable in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, workflow

I am using a workflow in PowerShell 5.1 and need to populate $workflow:xx where xx is dynamic based on the previous query

```
$test = @(1,2,3,4)
workflow my-test{
 param(
   $test
 )

$1=1
$2=2

 ForEach -Parallel ($num in $test){
  $workflow:1 #works but not what I need
  $workflow:$num #does not work
  $workflow:${$num} #does not work
  $workflow:${num} #does not work
 }

$2
}
```

Not the answer to my question but this is my work around.

```
$test = @(1,2,3,4)
workflow my-test{
 param(
   $test
 )

 ForEach -Parallel ($num in $test){
   write-output $num
 }

}

#returns array of all responses
$response = my-test
```

Comment: `ForEach -Parallel ($num in $test){ $num }` ?

Comment: I’ve updated the example for clarity. I would like to update $2 from inside the workflow.